# Notepad++ regex replace - replace all commas with \, within quotations

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I am trying to import a csv file into mysql, and I need to convert it into a proper format before importing.

If there's a comma in a column, the csv encloses it within double quotations, here's an example of a row without a comma, and a row with a comma:

```
1,Superman
2,"Batman,Flash"
```

What I need to do is to convert all columns which have commas to escape the comma and remove the quotations... such as `"Batman,Flash"` to `Batman\,Flash`

Here's what I have so far

```
Find: "(.*),(.*)"
Replace: \1\\,\2
```

However, there are two cases in which this does not work:

- It will only replace one comma if there's more than one comma withing a quoted column. So something like `"Batman,Flash,Robin"` will be converted to `Batman,Flash\,Robin`
- This doesn't work if the first column has a comma as well. For example, on a row such as `"1,2,3","Batman,Robin"`

How can I change the regexes to accommodate the two cases that don't yet work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but regex is **not** the tool for this. You must parse it.

Why?

Do you want to convert this?

```
"test\, w00t!"
```

Or what about this?

```
"test\\\\\, w00t!"
```

Heck, even this?

```
"tes\\","\"ing\,\\,"
```

Comment: My brain hurts now! What do you recommend? How do I parse this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can only hope someone else posts a solution for this, because I don't know any parser from the top of my head. You can make one yourself, but I don't think that's worth your time.

Comment: As a text editor it is not necessary to do everything in one pass. Some manual work may be involved.